# what is the problem in my code in android navigation drawer

Tags: android

[i had problem in applying java class for the navigation drawer
i had used to create the strings for navigation drawer open and close but still problem ActionBarToggleDrawerfuncytion](https://i.stack.imgur.com/F37Za.png)

Comment: Check your import for _ToolBar_. You have imported wrong _ToolBar_

Comment: Instead of posting a picture, post your code

Answer (score 0):

I think you import android.widget.Toolbar.Change your import to android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar and it should work.